# Intersection of closed real line intervals intersecting by pair is non empty

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove the following as part of an analysis exercise:

For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ a closed interval $[x_n,y_n]$.
Assuming that $[x_n,y_n]\cap [x_m,y_m] \neq \emptyset$ for every  $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$ prove $\cap _{n=1}^{\infty} [x_n,y_n] \neq \emptyset$

I have tried using $[x_n,y_n]\cap [x_m,y_m] = [max (x_n,x_m),min(y_n,y_m)]$, such that $\cap _{n=1}^{\infty} [x_n,y_n] = [max_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\; x_n, min_{m\in\mathbb{N}}\; y_m]$ which is non empty if the min of the ys is larger than the max of the xs. In the case where it is empty, it is easy to see that the two intervals corresponding to the max of xs, on one hand, and the min of the ys, on the other hand, have zero intersection, proving by contrapositive. But this does not look like the smartest way to prove it.

Comment: If every two given intervals intersect, then each $x_n$ must be a lower bound of all $y$-s and vice versa, each $y_m$ must be an upper bound of all $x$-es. So the interval $[\sup_n x_n, \inf_m y_m]$ contains at least one point _and_ is a subset of every interval given.

Comment: CiaPan has it, Note too though that an infinite set need not have a max or min, e.g. (1/n) has no minimum. But a set of reals bounded below has an infimum and vice versa- 0 in the case of (1/n).